# Why is this swift button setup crashing?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

I'm trying to programmatically add a button to a view along with its action method. The key thing is that the action method should be in the same file with the button so I can drop the file into other apps. When the button is tapped I want the action method to be executed but it crashes instead. It just gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS with no log output.

Here's a simplified test app with only two classes: ViewController and BlueButton:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let button = BlueButton(mainView: view)
        button.installButton()
    }
}

class BlueButton: NSObject {

    var mainView: UIView

    init(mainView: UIView) {
        self.mainView = mainView
    }

    func installButton() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 100, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Tap Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "someAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        mainView.addSubview(button)
    }

    func someAction() {
        println("this is someAction")
    }
}
```

Back trace shows nothing helpful. It ends with objc_msgSend. I tried many different ways of rearranging the code but nothing I tried worked. I added an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint but it doesn't get hit. I put a breakpoint on the someAction method just to be sure it isn't called -- it isn't. Can somebody tell me what's going on?

Comment: You need to give your classes better names! Your BlueButton class is not a button. That's very confusing!

Comment: You're right. I'll think of a better name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BlueButton` instance is deallocated when `viewDidAppear` returns because there is no longer a strong reference to it.

When the button is tapped, it tries to reference the instance, but it's been deallocated, which causes the crash.

You could resolve the issue a number of ways. The simplest would be to create a property in the `ViewController` class and store the `BlueButton` in it as long as the button is visible.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now - his BlueButton class is not in fact the button. It's just a kind of factory, and it goes out of existence when its job is done.

Comment: Another alternative to resolve this could be to derive `BlueButton` from `UIButton` which would require more code, however.